# Python arguments used in __getitem__?

Tags: python, parameters, arguments, tuples

```
class test:
    def func(self, *index): return index
    def __getitem__(self, *index): return index

t = test()

print(t.func(1))       # (1,)
print(t.func(1, 2))    # (1, 2)
print(t.func(1, 2, 3)) # (1, 2, 3)
```

So far so consistent.

```
print(t[1])            # (1,)
print(t[1, 2])         # ((1, 2),)
print(t[1, 2, 3])      # ((1, 2, 3),)
```

However now 1 argument calls differ. This makes it hard to to use "len(index)" to ask about the input count.

---

Q: Is there a way to ask how many parameters are being included in the indexer?

For example `t[1]` has 1 value, `t[1, 2]` has 2 values, and `t[1, 2, 3]` has 3 values.

---

---

A: (as it's closed)

`__getitem__` always receives 1 argument. Therefore it's clearer to use 'args' rather than '*args'.

This determines how many arguments were included in the square brackets.

```
class test:
    def __getitem__(self, index): return len(index) if type(index) == tuple else 1

t = test()
print(t[1])       # 1
print(t[1, 2])    # 2
print(t[1, 2, 3]) # 3
```

Answer uses info from "juanpa.arrivillaga" and "ekhumoro".

Comment: What exactly do you want to call `len` on? What exactly is your use of index notation supposed to model?

Comment: Don't use `*args`. Define it like this: `def __getitem__(self, key):`. Python will automatically convert the argument(s) to handle slices, etc correctly. You can then use `isinstance` to check what has been passed in.

Comment: Thank you @ekhumoro

Answer (score 1):

You fundamentally misunderstand how `__getitem__` works. It always receives a *single* argument, making `*args` unnecessary and confusing, because `arg` will always be `len(arg) == 1`.

Note, you aren't using arrays, you are using `tuple` objects. And in the first case, an `int` object.

```
t[1]
```

Passes `__getitem__` a single int because `1` is an int.

```
t[1, 2]
```

Passes `__getitem__` a single `tuple` because `1, 2` is a tuple.

If you wanted to pass a single-element tuple to `__getitem__` you would need:

```
t[1,]
```

Note, the only special-case syntax for agurments to `__getitem__` are slice, where:

```
t["start":"stop":"step"]
```

becomes a sort of `slice` object literal, so the argument would be:

```
slice('start', 'stop', 'step')
```

and similarly,

```
t["start":"stop":"step", 1:2]
```

would be a `tuple` of `slice` objects, so:

```
(slice('start', 'stop', 'step'), slice(1, 2, None))
```

TLDR:

> Is there a way to ask how many parameters are being included in the indexer?

there is no need, because **there will always be one argument passed to `__getitem__`*. You need the *type* of that argument, and perhaps subsequently, the *length* of that object.

Comment: See my answer and changes to the questions wording, I had to put it at the end of the question, using "args" rather than "*args" does make it clearer. It's not perfect but in most cases it should work.

Comment: @alan2here why do you still insist on talking about it in terms of how many arguments are being passed? *there is always one parameter*.

Comment: I've tried to rephrase it as being about how many comma delimited values are included in the square brackets of the call.